# How to format number cell in excel by Aspose?

Tags: java, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I am using Aspose for creating excel. I am getting few difficulties.

**1st issue**

`Cells.importResultSet` in this how to insert customDateFormatString

**2nd issue**

`Cells.importResultSet` in this how to insert customNumberFormatString

Please check the below example for number

```
10000 to $10,000
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You may put your desired custom date/time format string for the customDateFormatString parameter in Cells.importResultSet() overloaded method. See the sample line of code for your reference:
e.g
Sample code:

```
worksheet.getCells().importResultSet(rs, 0, 0, true, "d-mmm-yy", true);
```

2) It is better once you have imported data to Excel worksheet using Cells.importResultSet() method, you may apply your desired number formatting to the cells in the range/column accordingly, see the document for your reference:
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Setting+Display+Formats+of+Numbers+and+Dates

In your case, you should set the custom number format string as "$#,##0" for your requirements.

Comment: I tried that example. But here they talking about single cell. i like to put same style for column.

Comment: Well, you may format the whole row or column, see the document for your reference:
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Formatting+Rows+and+Columns
All you need to do is specify your desired Style object's options and make the relevant StyleFlag attributes on. Thanks.